# Perk requirement for spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do higher level spells become accessible when you have a certain level of the skill or do they become available only after acquiring the perk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The novice, apprentice, adept, and expert level spells are gotten from purchasing them (or in some cases, you can get them for free as loot or a reward).

The master level spells are acquirable generally after you complete your school-specific quests as a member of the College of Winterhold.

Perks don't add spells to your repertoire: they simply enhance the ones you already have.

Comment: Thanks... the point about casting as opposed to acquiring was more important than what I asked and is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: You do **not** need to meet a certain level in a skill before you can cast high-level spells of that school. You can cast any spell you have enough magicka to cast. The level cutoffs are merely to get the corresponding perks to lessen the magicka cost.

Comment: @StrixVaria Reverted: not sure why I added that onto my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you have to be a certain level to cast any spell or have the perk. You just have to have enough magicka to cast it. I know this because I was casting the storm atronach spell very early. The perk just halves the amount of magicka it takes to cast spells of that level.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be a certain level to find spells,otherwise they won't exist eg.if you aren't level 25 or higher you can't find telkinisis in the labyrinthian.Perks only improve the efficiency of spells,making them cost less magicka and do more damage